# Opening a remote machine's Windows C drive

Tags: windows, windows-xp, system-administration

I'm trying to locally mount a machine's C drive that is on my LAN.  I need to able to browse the contents of the other machine when tracing through code.  I once saw a sys admin do some crazy windows incantation from the cmd prompt.  Something like
$remote_machine/local_access/C

Is anyone familiar with how this is done?

Comment: Thank you oh holy keepers of the stack overflow purity for censoring my question.  Should I go around and close all your tool questions?  Windows is a tool.  Mounting drives is a tool. Next time I see your question about emacs, should I censor you, because its not programming related?

Comment: I hate it when they close questions. I don't understand why this one is off-topic.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If it's not the Home edition of XP, you can use `\\servername\c$`

Mark Brackett's comment:

> Note that you need to be an
>   Administrator on the local machine, as
>   the share permissions are locked down

Comment: Note that you need to be an Administrator on the local machine, as the share permissions are locked down.

Comment: what method of access is this called when you use that syntax through a Windows Explorer to connect to a remote machine?

Answer (score 10):

If you need a drive letter (some applications don't like UNC style paths that start with a machine-name) you can "map a drive" to a UNC path. Right-click on "My Computer" and select Map Network Drive... or use this command line:

NET USE z: \server\c$\folder1\folder2

NET USE y: \server\d$

Note that you can map drive-to-drive or drill down and map to sub-folder.

Answer (score 8):

By default, Windows makes the root of each drive available (provided you've got Administrator privileges) as (e.g.) `\\server\c$`. These are known as [Administrative Shares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share).