# Copy file from one machine to another(batch script)

Tags: python, batch-file, command-line, cmd, batch-processing

I am tying to copy file from one machine to another possibly a batch script so that I can automate

I am trying something like this.

```
copy C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\result.txt \\(IP address of remote machine)\C:\folder1\result.txt
```

Comment: can you provide the error message ? I woud say that a second `\\` is missing at start of the destination path.

Comment: network path was not found is what I see @C.LECLERC

Comment: Are you able to access the destination folder with windows folder browser ? according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606534/opening-a-remote-machines-windows-c-drive specified path has an incorrect syntax (missing `$`)

Comment: `\\servername\sharename\folder\file.ext` **NOTE** NO SEMICOLONS. `\\127.0.0.1\C$\Users\Administrator\Desktop\result.txt`. `C$` is a share that admins only can use and is auto generated by windows. `$` means it's a hidden share.

Comment: If any spaces in the name enclose with quotes. `copy "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\result.txt" "\\127.0.0.1\C$\folder1\result.txt"`